# How to count Maximum rows in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, count, rows

I have the code for the next button. The data in the database show up normally. 

The problem is when I click next button, the data will be repeated again as --> data1 > data2 > data3 > data1 > data2...

I've to been told that I should count the maximum rows but I didn't know how to do it; I've search for the coding as well, but nothing that I understand came out.

Please help me~~~ (I am not very good with English, sorry)

> Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
>   System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
>
> ```
>     btnBack.Enabled = True
>
>     da.Fill(dt)
>     If position >= 0 Then
>
>         position = position + 1
>         Me.lblID.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("RefNo")
>         Me.txtboxName.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("Name")
>         Me.rtxtboxAddress.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("Address")
>         Me.txtboxContactNo.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("ContNo")
>         Me.txtboxFaxNo.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("FaxNo")
>         Me.txtboxBrand.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("Brand")
>         Me.txtboxModel.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("Model")
>         Me.txtboxSN.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("SN")
>         Me.rtxtboxProblems.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("Problems")
>         Me.rtxtboxTechRemark.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("TechRemark")
>         Me.rtxtboxServChange.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("ServiceChange")
>         Me.rtxtboxPartChange.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("PartsChange")
>         Me.txtboxTotal.Text = dt.Rows(position).Item("TotalPrice")
>
>     End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

I don't know if this is also need to be told, but... there is two different class

 1) database.vb - sql coding

 2) forms.vb - coding for my visual basic form

Please help me!!

**THANKS EVERYONE WHO HELO ME WITH THE ANSWERS!! I HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION OF THE QUESTION AFTER RE-FIGURED THE CODING.**


 I didn't figure out the position value and the row value is same. My value of position = 0 and dt.Rows.Count = 4, since I have 4 data; so when the position = 0, the row = 1. I get confused about that; I thought both value is starting with 0.

Comment: Huh, I'm really surprised you're not getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException`... it [sounds like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx) that's what you should get if go past the maximum number of rows. Either way, you can do `dt.Rows.Count` to get the number of rows in your `DataTable`.

Comment: @JeffBridgman I am sorry... but I don't understand. Where do I have to write dt.Rows.Count in the coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more code... this is *bad* code... don't rely on it for production since I'm sure there are plenty of corner cases it doesn't handle, but I wanted to give you a picture of how you could handle it and at least a glimpse of stuff you might need to worry about (e.g. 0 rows in the data table). Please work through this and try to understand the code... don't simply copy/paste.

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click

    If position >= dt.Rows.Count Then
        // No more rows to show after this one, so disable the next button
        btnNext.Enabled = False
    End If

    // Put check for zero in btnBack.Click to make sure it doesn't go below 0
    // I'm assuming position starts off at 0, and that you're showing the very
    // first row by default
    position += 1

    // This is to handle a condition like having 0 rows in the data table, 
    // in which case don't want to do the next part...
    If position > dt.Rows.Count Then Exit Sub

    // Only necessary once really, but we'll do it each time anyway...
    btnBack.Enabled = True

    da.Fill(dt) 

    position += 1

    // Update various textboxes and labels...
End Sub
```

Comment: I have try to understand the coding and use it. But there is a problem also... Sorry for this, but do please help me fix it.  I disable the line **position += 1** because it make the rows jump from data1 > data3 without showing data2, although if I click the previous button, then the data2 will show up (so it is not like the data is missing).  But if I disable that line, then data3 is not show up (only data1 > data2)! I didn't know why, but the next button was disabled, so didn't that mean that it reached the max row which isn't the last one?

Comment: The index starts at zero... when you first enter this function is the value of position 0? Try setting a breakpoint to see what the value is.

Comment: The value of position = 0.

Comment: Hmm... sorry, I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

`dt.Rows.Count` is the number of rows in the Rows collection.  Anytime you want to check the whether you've reached the maximum number of rows compare the row count to dt.Rows.Count

Comment: I am sorry... but I don't understand. Where do I have to write dt.Rows.Count in the coding?

Comment: I added more explanation

Answer (score 0):

da, dt, and position should be declared outside your sub above. The Fill statement should also be executed outside the sub.

In the sub:

```
       If position >= 0 and position  < dr.rows.count then
           do stuff above
       else
           Beep ' out of range
       end if
```